# How to run 32-bit dll (AxInterop.DHTMLEDLib) in 64-bit win 7 operating system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, dhtml, rundll32

dhtml editing control (AxInterop.DHTMLEDLib.dll) is working fine in 32-bit win xp and win 7 but when this control is used in 64-bit operating system following exception is shown on

```
this.AxDHTMLEdit1 = new AxDHTMLEDLib.AxDHTMLEdit();
```

[image]

Exception is shown because 32-bit dll is not working in 64-bit system but the project requirements are that it must also run in current 64-bit win 7.

I have searched for the latest version of AxInterop.DHTMLEDLib compatible for 64-bit systems but did't found any.The only possible solution available on the net is shown here but there is no code given for that

http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/

The above mentioned way is shown in majority of the web sites without any code given against it.

How to find a way to run 32-bit AxInterop.DHTMLEDLib.dll in 64-bit win 7 operating system or if there is any alternative to this dll available for 64-bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell .Net run-time and OS that you are a 32-bit application.  See [running 32-bit process on 64-bit OS](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os/) on how do to it.